# wcf with common.logging issue

Tags: c#-4.0, iis-7, log4net, common.logging

Interesting issue I'm trying to solve.
So here we have got simple wcf service running on iis7. Code related to common.logging look like:

```
using Common.Logging;

private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

log.Error("Opened Sagas Monitoring Service: {0}", ex);
```

web.config configurations:

```
<configSections>
<sectionGroup name="commonLogging">
  <section name="logging" type="Common.Logging.ConfigurationSectionHandler, Common.Logging" />
</sectionGroup>
```

```
<commonLogging>
<logging>
  <factoryAdapter type="Common.Logging.Log4Net.Log4NetLoggerFactoryAdapter, Common.Logging.Log4Net">
    <arg key="configType" value="FILE-WATCH" />
    <arg key="configFile" value="~/log4net.config" />
  </factoryAdapter>
</logging>
```

log4net.config is in same deploy folder as web.config with all assemblies we need.

So the issue is next. After we call service it does not create logger. And no exceptions. But while our service ON and we change anyhow our web.config file in deploy folder it will immediately pick up logger. Problem seems to be with FactoryAdapter. Any ideas?